# wp_loop results in one conteiner but in two divs?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have extra field in my template, it looks like:
      " >

```
    <div class="entry-content clearfix">
        <div class="col-left">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <?php
                if(function_exists('get_field')) {
                    $sc = get_field('second_column');
                    echo apply_filters( the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ), $sc );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div><!-- #post-## -->
```

It should be like that: col-left displaying posts (recent 10) and in col-right displaying thumnail to each post.

How I should put while, to have all content inside this template? Sitting a while on it, and no idea for it. The best, but not working as I need, is:

```
<?php if ( $category_posts->have_posts() )  ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="entry-content clearfix">
        <div class="col-left">
            <?php while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            <?php
                while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post();
                if(function_exists('get_field')) {
                    $sc = get_field('second_column');
                    echo apply_filters( the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ), $sc );
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div><!-- #post-## -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomu, if you want to run loop twice on same page than you have to use `<?php rewind_posts(); ?>`. You can try below code.

```
<?php if ( $category_posts->have_posts() )  ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class="entry-content clearfix">
    <div class="col-left">
        <?php while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
       <?php rewind_posts(); ?>     
        <?php
            while ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post();
            if(function_exists('get_field')) {
                $sc = get_field('second_column');
                echo apply_filters( the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ), $sc );
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Comment: In this way I multiply divs col-left and col-right. Thing is all content results should be in one col-left, and all thumbnail results in one col-right. I have try now it: inside col-left whilewhile ( $category_posts->have_posts() ) : $category_posts->the_post();  the_content(); and in col-right while ( $category_posts_thumbnail->have_posts() ) : $category_posts_thumbnail->the_post(); but in col-right only first img is fine

Comment: Tomu, I got your point now try to run code with <?php rewind_posts(); ?>. I have updated my answer you can try it now.

Comment: That`s it! Good enough! Thank you!